# Was Solomon Northup poisoned?

Tags: plot-explanation, 12-years-a-slave

In *12 Years a slave*, Solomon Northup is rendered unconscious before he is abducted.

He is seen drinking wine with his meal beforehand, and his captors are insistent he drinks more & more & more....

The film doesn't make clear whether he was simply intoxicated, or if something was placed in his drink to render him unconscious.

Does anyone know what really happened to him?

Comment: From his behaviour he seemed more sick than drunk, but I agree that it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Wikipedia [synopsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Years_a_Slave#Synopsis) of the book the film is based on, he was drugged.

However, the reason this may not have been made clear in the movie could have been deliberate. The director or writers may have wanted the audience to be oblivious as to what actually happened, as Solomon may have been oblivious himself.